# Reusing constants in the same angular module

Tags: angularjs

I have made my custom enum (see code), and I would like to reuse the constants declared as `FOO` and `BAR` without having to write the value of the constants again in the `types` array. How would I go about doing that?

```
var myApp = angular.module('app');
myApp.constant('MyEnum', {
FOO: "foo",
BAR: "bar",

types: [
    {id: 0, value: 'foo', label:"Foo"},
    {id: 1, value: 'bar', label:"Bar"}
]
});
```

I would like to do something like this in the `types` array:

```
types: [
    {id: 0, value: this.FOO, label:"Foo"},
    {id: 1, value: this.BAR, label:"Bar"}
]
```

but doing it like this gives me errors. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use intermediate variables for this. Maybe to store them in the closure so you don't pollute scope with unneeded variables. For example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app');
myApp.constant('MyEnum', function() {

   var __FOO = "foo",
       __BAR = "bar";

    return {

        FOO: __FOO,
        BAR: __BAR,

        types: [
            {id: 0, value: __FOO, label: "Foo"}, 
            {id: 1, value: __BAR, label: "Bar"}
        ]
    }
}());
```

Comment: Thanks! is it common to use two underscores in the intermediate variables?

Comment: @John They generally means "private" variables.